# only one link functioning in css only accordion

Tags: css

I am trying to show a CSS only vertical accordion inside a page having other things. Only the accordion is not showing properly - the las / bottom-most link opens the intended text - other links do not. But this same code works when written in a different HTML document having only the accordion.

I have gut feeling that the problem is in the CSS and about sizing or positioning (absolute / relative) - but cannot find it out.

Hope to get some light ...

My HTML and CSS are like below:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main1(with-accordion).css"      media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    We do things to help you &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div id="inner_header">
        to your satisfaction .... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked id="tab1">
            <label for="tab1">Who are we</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <span>
                        Contents of tab1 goes here:
                        Visions etc.
                    </span>
                </div>
         </li>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">What we do</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <span>Contents of tab2 goes here:
                        Credentials, visions etc.
                     </span>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
            <label for="tab3">Contact us</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <span>
                        Contents of tab3 goes here:
                        Contents etc.
                    </span>

                </div>


                    <form method="post" id="data">
                    <fieldset > <legend> Data </legend>
                        <br>

                        <span class="inputs">
                            <label>First Name :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="First_Name" size="50">
                        </span>

                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <span class="inputs">
                            <label>Middle Name :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Middle_Name" size="50">
                        </span>

                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <span class="inputs">
                            <label>Last Name :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Last_Name" size="50">
                        </span>

                        <br>
                        <br>


                            <span class="inputs">
                                <label class="form_label">Address 1 : </label>
                                <input type="text" name="Address1" size="50">
                            </span>

                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <span class="inputs">
                                <label class="form_label">Address 2 :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Address2" size="50">
                            </span>

                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <span class="inputs">
                                <label class="form_label">Pincode :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pincode" size="20">
                            </span>

                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <span class="inputs">
                                <label class="form_label">Country :</label>
                                <select>
                                    <option value="Afghanistan"  title="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                    <option value="Åland Islands" title="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Albania" title="Albania">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="Algeria" title="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="American Samoa" title="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Andorra" title="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                    <option value="Angola" title="Angola">Angola</option>
                                    <option value="Anguilla" 
                                </select>
                            </span>


                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <span class="inputs">
                            <label class="form_label">Email ID :</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" size="30">
                        </span>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                    <input class="cancel_button" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
                    <input class="submit_button" type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </li>
    </ul>    
</div>



 <!-- The following code block is the problem area-->
 <div id="accordion">
 <ul>
    <li> <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>




        <div id ="tab1" class="accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean  
        </div>


    <li> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <div id ="tab2" class="accordion-content">
            Cum eu oporteat voluptatum, mandamus explicari ius eu. Discere 
        </div>



    <li> <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
        <div id ="tab3" class="accordion-content">
            No amet nullam detracto usu, vix posse iracundia deterruisset 
        </div>



    <li> <a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
        <div id ="tab4" class="accordion-content">
            In a professional context it often happens that private or 
        </div>


</ul>
</div>


<!-- The above code block is the problem area-->



<div id="right_bar">Fixed contents here ... </div>

<div id="footer">Page created by: Sukalyan Ghoshal. Email:sukalayn_g@yahoo.com </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
padding-top: 0;
height: 200px;
line-height: 250%; /**** This line is used to control spacing between the  two lines in the header *****/
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: right;
font-size: 3em;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: navy;
width: 100%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient (to right, mediumblue, darkturquoise);
background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, mediumblue, darkturquoise);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, mediumblue, darkturquoise);
background: linear-gradient(to right, mediumblue, darkturquoise);
}

#inner_header {
display: block;
margin-top: 0;
line-height: 20%; /**** This line is also used to control spacing between   the two lines in the header *****/
}



/*accordion css*/

#accordion {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 200px;
}

#accordion ul {
position: relative;
top: 0;
list-style-type: none;


}

#accordion ul a {
display: block;
}

#accordion div {
display: none;
}

#accordion ul li + div:target {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.accordion-content {
width: 200px;
}

/* end of accordion css */

#nav {
position: absolute;
left: 225px;
top: 200px;
eight: 600px;
width: 775px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: green;
}

#nav ul {

list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
display: inline-block; /******* Display property of the li must be set to  inline-block along with that of the labels for showing labels side by side *****/
height: 30px;
}

#nav ul li input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}

#nav ul li label {

float: left;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: -5px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
width: 125px;
height: 2.1em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;
overflow: auto;
background-color: white;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: green;    
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-width: 0;
line-height: 2.1em;
white-space: nowrap; /****** height=line-height with white-space=nowrap makes text inside an element vertically centered ********/
}


#nav div {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 56px;
left: 35px;
width: 700px;
height: 543px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: green;
text-align: center;
}

#nav .content span {

vertical-align: middle;
}

/****** The next two block must be like this to the minimum to show a  behaviour of tabs and tabbed content showing not to have a seperation between  them ******/

#nav input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
display: block;
background-color: pink;
z-index: -1;    /****The z-index property of the labels and the <div>    element showing tab content must be staggered like this *****/
}

#nav input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
border-bottom-width: 0;
height: 2.2em; /*** In this particular design em has been used for height of  labels for ease of toggling border between tab and content *****/
background-color: pink;
z-index: 2;     /****The z-index property of the labels and the <div>  element showing tab content must have staggered z-index like this *****/
}

/****** The previous two block must be like this to the minimum to show a behaviour of tabs and tabbed content showing not to have a seperation between them ******/

#data {

position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
width: 500px;
height: 550px;
display: none;
}


#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs {
position: relative;
left: 50px;
width: 100px;
}


#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form { /**** This styling is required for  showing the form. Without this the fields in the form do not show up. *****/
display:inline-block;
}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset {

 position: absolute;
width: 565px;
left: -10px;
}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs > label {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 3px 13px 0 0;
text-align: right;
width: 140px;
background-color:pink;
border-width: 0;
}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs >  input[type="text"] {

padding-top: -5px;
 border:none; 
 -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
 -moz-border-radius:5px; 
 border-radius:5px; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
 box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
 height:25px; 
 line-height:25px; 
 width:200px; 
 text-indent:5px;
 }


 #nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs > select {

 padding-top: -5px;
 border:none; 
 -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
 -moz-border-radius:5px; 
 border-radius:5px; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
 height:25px; 
 line-height:25px; 
  width:200px; 
  text-indent:5px;
  }

  #nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs >  input[type="email"] {

   padding-top: -5px;
   border:none; 
   -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
   -moz-border-radius:5px; 
   border-radius:5px; 
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
   box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
   height:25px; 
   line-height:25px; 
   width:200px; 
   text-indent:5px;

}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ form  > fieldset > .inputs > select {
  width: 250px;
}
#nav input[id="tab3"]:not(:checked) ~ .cancel_button {
  display: none;
}


#nav input[id="tab3"]:not(:checked) ~ .submit_button {
  display: none;
}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ .cancel_button {

 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 left: 400px;
 top: 540px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 5px;

}

#nav input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ .submit_button {

position: absolute;
width: 100px;
left: 550px;
top: 540px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#right_bar {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 1002px;
height: 600px;
width: 340px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: orange;
}
#footer {
position:absolute;
left: 0;
top: 1200px;
width: 100%;
/*border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;*/
font-size: 1.25em;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: white;
background-color: mediumorchid;
height: 100px;  /***** The next three lines together vertically center the writing in the <div> ******/
line-height: 100px; /**** height and line-height must be same with white-space having a value of "nowrap" *****/
white-space: nowrap;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient (mediumorchid, violet);
background: -o-linear-gradient(mediumorchid, violet);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(mediumorchid, violet);
background: linear-gradient(mediumorchid, violet);

}
```

...Sorry for the long HTML and CSS ...

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on what's happening when you click on the  accordion.

Comment: Hi Sharif, only the content in the div after the fourth tab of the accordion (named Tab4 here) is showing and nothing shows when I click on the buttons 1, 2 and 3 of the accordion (named Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 in the present case). I have not yet given them the look of accordion yet by visual styling of the links though ....

Answer (score 0):

If you set multiple bookmarks with the same ID html never work, remember to set your code well or you'll never find the errors, also have left open many tags, (I've closed myself), click the JSFiddle link below for the correction .

The problem was in this part of code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#tab10">Tab1</a></li>
    <div id="tab10" class="accordion-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
    </div>
    <li> <a href="#tab20">Tab2</a></li>
    <div id="tab20" class="accordion-content">
        Cum eu oporteat voluptatum, mandamus explicari ius eu. Discere
    </div>
    <li> <a href="#tab30">Tab3</a></li>
    <div id="tab30" class="accordion-content">
        No amet nullam detracto usu, vix posse iracundia deterruisset
    </div>
    <li> <a href="#tab40">Tab4</a></li>
    <div id="tab40" class="accordion-content">
        In a professional context it often happens that private or
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsbeuv59/4/

*I set hashtag with big characters to make sure the resolution of the problem in future cases*

Comment: Thank you so much Brombin ...... that solves it. It would be of much help if you can suggest any application for debugging such things - i.e. which highlights and gives warnings about - say multiple use of ID, variable name, open tags etc.

Comment: You're still at the beginning you should atom (atom.io), does not tell you all the mistakes but offers a clean work surface to work on. Anything that you yourself could be Dreamweaver but any developer will recommend an IDE never like that. Otherwise you can try NetBeans or eclipse.

Comment: I use sublime text - how do you rate it?

Comment: Not bad I used it for several years

Comment: Use stackoverflow vote system to help the community. @SukalyanGhoshal